# Jetty: load a context from another jar

Tags: java, maven, jetty, spi

I've built an application that loads multiple plugins over SPI. Each plugin has to implement the `FrameworkPlugin` interface.

```
public interface FrameworkPlugin {
    ...
    ContextHandler getWebContent();
    String getPluginID();
    ...

}
```

An example implementation would be

```
...
ContextHandler getWebContent() {
   WebAppContext wac=new WebAppContext();
   wac.setBaseResource(new ResourceCollection(new String[] {"./src/main/webapp"}));
   return wac;
}
...
```

The Main-Project runs a single Jetty instance, which should be used by all plugins providing web-based services. A plugin has to be able to configure it's individual environment within its own context, except the base URL, which is managed by the main project.

```
...
for (FrameworkPlugin p : PLUGINS) {
    ContextHandler h= p.getWebContent();
    h.setContextPath("/plugin/"+p.getPluginID().toString());
    collection.addHandler(h);
}
jettyInstance.setHandler(collection);
...
```

So in theory, plugins should be accessible under `/plugin/<id>`. Unfortunately Jetty throws an IllegalArgumentException, because plugins set `./src/main/webapp` as resource base, which does not exist in the main project.

So how to supply a context handler via the plugin interface?

Deploying WARs is not an option, as the loading mechanism can't be changed. Everything has to be done by using the plugin interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this isn't going to be a WAR based project, then skip the use of `WebAppContext` entirely, and just use the `Handler` system in Jetty itself.

The `WebAppContext` is a specialized `Handler` meant to be used with a full blown and complete Web Application that follows the servlet spec.  It mandates behavior that is mandated by the servlet spec, from the mundane (how url mapping order behaves), past the black art (per element descriptor order lookup and override), to the complex (webapp classloader isolation).

The [`Handler`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Handler.html) system in Jetty can be 1..n `Handlers`, in a Tree (via [HandlerCollections](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/HandlerCollection.html)), sometimes with [Context](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ContextHandler.html), [mutable Handler collections](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/HandlerCollection.html#HandlerCollection(boolean)), and all exists at the same classloader as the server (if you want it to).  Feel free to url map with regex, or your own implementation of [level 3 URI templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-1.2).  Completely up to you what you want to do with it.  You have many pre-built Handlers and base Handler to build up from.

You'll [still have access](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Handler.html#handle(java.lang.String,%20org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)) to the standard `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse`, along with the async processing and I/O that those provide.  But you'll also have access to the raw internal [`Request`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Request.html) object which offers even more features over the `HttpServletRequest`.

Incidentally, many servlet based applications support plugins now.  Most accomplish this using Controller Servlets, or Filters, or manipulation of the ServletContext's registrations.

Comment: Can you please define "Handler system" more precisely? Isn't `WebAppContext` is a Handler, and therefore part of the Handler system itself?

Comment: added some brief comments to answer, the topic is just too open ended / large to cover in detail.

Comment: A brief example of a handler (!=WebAppContext) serving JSF would do the job, no need for a never ending story.

Comment: Whoops, you are using JSF?  Then you require a WebAppContext, a Web Application, a proper ClassLoader and all of the Configurations that it implies.  JSF is just not capable of running outside of a WebAppContext, sorry. (I see the jsf tag now)